# block all connections connected to a boost signal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

boost signals allows temporarily blocking a connection via a connection member function. However, I have a single signal with many connections. The connections are stored and maintained by their respective listeners. Now the broadcaster decides that it wants to stop sending signals for a while. There does not seem to be a way to iterate all connections of a signal or disable the whole signal temporarily. This seems strange to me as surely such a mechanism must exist internally in order for the signal to reach all of its subscribers when signalled...
Am I missing something? How can I temporarily disable a signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that directly.  If you are willing to permanently disconnect all slots, you can use the `disconnect_all_slots()` method.  For example:

```
boost::signal<int ()> foo;
...
foo.disconnect_all_slots();
```

If you need to temporarily block them, the best workaround I can come up with is to use a custom combiner that emulates that behaviour.

```
#include <boost/signals.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//Define a reusable combiner that allows all slots to be blocked
template <typename Combiner>
struct blockable {
   typedef typename Combiner::result_type result_type;

   blockable() : blocked(false), combiner() {}

   //Block or unblock all slots
   void block() {blocked = true;}
   void unblock() {blocked = false;}

   template <typename InputIterator>
   result_type operator()(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
      //Either call into inner combiner, or throw if all slots are blocked
      if (!blocked) return combiner(first, last);
      throw std::runtime_error("All slots are blocked");
   }
 private:
   bool blocked;
   Combiner combiner;
};

//Quick and dirty sample using the blockable combiner
int bar() {
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   boost::signal<int (), blockable<boost::last_value<int> > > foo;
   foo.connect(&bar);
   try {
      //show that it works
      int x = foo();
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
      //Now block all slots
      foo.combiner().block();
      int y = foo();
      //This won't run since the last call to foo() should throw
      std::cout << y << std::endl;
   } catch (std::exception& e) {
      //Should get here via 2nd call to foo()
      std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```